# what is negative Position number meaning google webmaster tools

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console

today i review my Search Analytics in google webmaster console
i see some keyword has negative Position number
[image]

what does it mean??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Webmaster Console average position is reportedly buggy but in your case, it's a difference between last month avg position and this month avg position.

In July/August you had ranking position 130 and in Aug/Sep your ranking position was nill, Google considered it as zero so as per calculations you lost 130 positions and difference is -130.

Let me know if anything is still unclear!

Comment: thank you , in some case it seems there is no data because website not registered in GWMT